# Issue with transform 3D

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**JQuery**

```
 $(window).load(function () {
      $(".Flipbook").css({ 'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300)', 'visibility': 'visible' });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="Flipbook">

</div>
</div>
```

I am applying the Transform to the div through jQuery on window.load event.
When I refresh the page 2 to 3 times, then the following style is applying:

```
transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
```

I want to apply the following transform when the page gets loaded.

```
transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300)
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
The issue is with the Panzoom transform.

**JQuery**

```
$(window).load(function () {
      $(".Flipbook").panzoom("resetPan", {
                animate: false,
                silent: true
            });
  });
```

The issue is partially resolved. The Mozilla Firefox and Safari having some issues;
They are taking `Matrix()` initially, later chaning to `translate3d`

How to stop the Firefox and Safari from taking `tranlate3d` option for `Transform` and make it take `Matrix()`?

Comment: This is working for me check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/sbUQg/)

Answer (score -3):

this is part of w3schools definition about transform in css:
Browser Support
Internet Explorer Firefox Opera Google Chrome Safari

The transform property is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, and Opera.

Internet Explorer 9 supports an alternative, the -ms-transform property (2D transforms only).

Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the -webkit-transform property (3D and 2D transforms).

Opera supports 2D transforms only.

what is your browser?
may be this is the problem...

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is causing issue in all browsers.

Comment: [w3schools is an unreliable and patchy source of information](http://www.w3fools.com/). For support reference, try [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) instead: here are their support tables for [3D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) and [2D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Comment: @Barney You are wrong, w3schools is a nice reference in laconic way for basic and middle information about web programming and is completely reliable... I learned a lot from w3schools and compared those information with other and there wasn't any thing wrong, even just a single world... I'm not saying that this is the best and more complete reference but it's reliable...